# webpack alias with react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, alias

I have tried so many times, I have consulted so many websites and I have even bullied Chat GPT so many times.
I can't seem to find the solution. I am new to React.

So I try to create an alias in a react application with webpack and I get this error.

Module not found : Error : Can't resolve **'@public/assets/numbers.json'** in **'/path/to/test-component/src'**

Here is the location of my file: public/assets/numbers.json
And the location of the file in which I call it: src/Ap.tsx

**tsconfig.json:**

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
    "@public/*": ["./public/*"]
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {  
    resolve: {
        alias:{
        "@public": path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/")
        }
    }
};
```

I tried almost everything